# Win32com outlook filter by date stopped working

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I have a script, that shows email's from some range of dates. It was working till 29 of april, and now, it doesn't filter correctly...

```
import win32com.client

import os 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')

messages = mapi.Folders("myemail@gmail.com").Folders("Inbox").Items

today = datetime.today()

start_time = today.replace(month=4,day=20, hour=0, minute=0, second=0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p')
end_time = today.replace(month=5,day=2,hour=20, minute=0, second=0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p')

messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + start_time
+ "' And [ReceivedTime] <= '" + end_time + "'")


messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", Descending=True)

for message in list(messages)[:5]:
    print(message.Subject, message.ReceivedTime, message.SenderEmailAddress)
```

I was using https://www.codeforests.com/2021/05/16/python-reading-email-from-outlook-2/ as a tutorial.

Any ideas why it's not working as intended?
Script doesn't show any messages at all right now.

Comment: If you want help with with why it's not working as intended, it would be helpful to explain what *is* intended.  I  know that's perfectly obvious to you  but...

Comment: What is the final query that you pass to Items.Restrict?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko  I mean, everything is in the code above... only query about range of date.

`messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + start_time
+ "' And [ReceivedTime] <= '" + end_time + "'")`

@BoarGules It should show emails from certain range of date only. 

For some reasons, it was working correctly 2 weeks ago, I didn't change anything, and now it's not showing emails correctly

Comment: That is your code that builds it. Assign that filter to a dedicated variable, and then put a breakpoint and look at its value before passing it on to `Restrict`

Comment: I had a similar issue. Posted all the details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77215287/python-win32com-restrict-method-using-receivedtime-not-fetching-emails

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that dates are formatted properly. Although dates and times are typically stored with a `Date` format, the `Find` and `Restrict` methods require that the date and time be converted to a string representation. To make sure that the date is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, use the `Format` function. For example, a VBA macro which shows how to use the `Format` function:

```
sFilter = "[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format("5/02/22 3:30pm", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
```

Also it makes sense to `Sort` the collection before applying filters.

Read more about the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply.
I've checked format by using strftime. And it was OK, week ago or so...